# Iteration count and where clause

Tags: mysql

i need some help.
I have many users with their date of birth:

```
SELECT COUNT(or SUM) ()    FROM ()

WHERE () = ''  

AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())=18(age)
```

I have to calculate count, sum, average and things like these of a column many times by changing only the age in the where clause. 
How can I make sure i do not waste time running the query so many times as many years are?
I have to go from 18 to 65:

```
SELECT COUNT(or SUM) () FROM ()

WHERE () = ''  AND () = ''

AND ()<'' 

AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())=**19,29,21 etc**.

I would like this columns results:

count()  18

count()  19 etc

or

sum () 18

sum() 19 etc
```

Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Return the result of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` as a column, then use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS age, COUNT(*)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY age
```